# Inflection - German rules (Rails or others)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What are the best Rails inflection rules for the German language out there? Examples from other languages to be ported would be great, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience looking for a complete set of German inflection rules is hopeless. Even the default ones (English) are incomplete.

Here's what I do in my Rails applications.

- Only use pluralize and Co. for code identifiers.
- For model names (and all "user facing" strings) use the I18n API even if there's only one language.

Configuring the I18n stuff is slightly more work to set up, on the other hand your code is no longer cluttered with end-user messages.

Comment: This means you'd name models, controllers, etc. in proper English and use the i18n API for translating any user facing content into just one language? Sounds good to me. Thanks a lot!